# Как безопасно завершить процесс в multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Допустим я запустил процесс,

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=someFunc, args=("arg1", "arg2"))
```

после того как он отработает, с ним надо что-то делать?

Comment: Я полагаю, что в этом коде будет запущен не один процесс? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для запуска процесса вызывается `start()`. Чтобы подождать завершения процесса или таймаута, следует вызывать `join()`. Последний метод возвращает `None`.

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=someFunc, args=("arg1", "arg2"))
p.start()
p.join()
```

[Здесь](https://tatyderb.gitbooks.io/python-express-course/content/chapter_stdlib/ipc_multiprocessing.html) есть хорошие примеры на тему многопоточности в Python